# SDL1.2, Window in another window

Tags: c++, ubuntu, cross-platform, sdl

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 here and developing an SDL1.2 app in c++. What I would like to achieve is that the user could open like a "Preferences" window or something from the "Main" window (both window should have a titlebar etc). I'd also like to have this program be able to run cross-platform, and SDL2 is not an option, either.

Is this achievable in any way? What I could think of so far is writing another SDL program that will be called from inside the 'main' program, but that would include some system() calls, and anyways, it's not the best solution IMO.

Comment: Why SDL2 is not an option?

Comment: It is not in the official repositories for Ubuntu, and I would not like my program to depend on PPAs.
On the other hand, can this be done in SDL2?

Answer (score 1):

SDL only supports a single window. If you upgrade to SDL2, it supports multiple windows, though you can't put one window inside of another window.

If you want this functionality without upgrading, you'll have to render the window-in-a-window yourself.